# Using HtmlAgilityPack XPath to search for item by both class name and child item

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using Xpath to extract a html node by it class name and child attribute. My Html is something like

```
<div class="className"><div><a href="/abc/def/"></a></div></div>
```

I try with `//div[@class='className' and div/a[@href='/abc/def/']]` but it is not work.

Comment: The XPath expression is correct, _what_ does not work? Do you get an error? The wrong results?

Comment: My guess is that the outer `<div>` has more than one CSS class set. In that case `//div[contains(@class, 'className') ...]` is what you actually need.

Comment: @aloisdg Your edit is an incorrect one, even if it was approved by everyone except me. "and" is part of the XPath expression and your edit has essentially broken it. The parentheses would also have been a hint. Please only edit if you are familiar with the tag.

Comment: @MathiasMüller ok no problem.

Comment: yes it works. I actually make mistake in other section. Thank a lot for all of your efforts.